# Lightweight network packet capture solution for windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireshark, sniffing

I'm looking for a lightweight packet capture solution for Windows. It needs to capture all packets on a physical network device and write them to a file (preferably `.pcap`, because that's easiest for my postprocessing). I'd go with wireshark, but that maintains a graphical list and keeps a lot of the captured packets in memory, which may affect the way the system runs.

Is there something similar that will simply capture and write to a file? (All analysis can be done afterwards.)

Comment: Wireshark has a command-line `tshark` tool, which is just like tcpdump.

Answer (score 2):

[WinPcap for Windows](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm)

[TechNet Blogs Network Monitor](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/)

[Microsoft Network Monitor -> Microsoft Message Analyzer!](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.ru/2012/09/goodbye-microsoft-network-monitor-hello.html)

[Network Monitor Open Source Parsers](http://nmparsers.codeplex.com/releases)

Download [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865)